# Updating Timeframe

Tags: updating

How often should I update my portable LaTeX flash drive?  It seems that new updates are developed each month, and it is a real hassle to check for new updates too often.  I was advised to check for updates "often" since an obsolete version can cause certain code not to work.

Comment: It depends. If you need to use the latest version of lualatex with tikz 3 and a latex3 regexp code, probably every day. But the vast majority of latex documents would process quite happily on a latex release from  ten years ago.

Comment: TeX Live do not recommend updating unless you need the updates. That is, you can but they stress that this is not necessary or even recommended. The latest yearly release (TL 2014 now) is better tested than any subsequently updated version. That said, if you use the net installer, you get whatever updates there are on install so the 'better tested' bit is irrelevant. But there's still no need if what you have works for you. There is nothing wrong with using an earlier year's TL either, as David Carlisle says.